# Swift 3 UIButton addTarget not working

Tags: swift3, uibutton

I have created a button in my `UIView` but can't figure out why it wont work. The same code works fine in other `UIViews`. Here is my code. I have tried different combinations of initializing the button with a frame or by using constraints but it makes no difference.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("BACK", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(Constants.APP_TEXT_COLOR, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = Constants.APP_HEADER_FONT
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBackButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    backView.addSubview(backButton)

    view.addSubview(backgroundView)

    backgroundView.addSubview(webView)

    backgroundView.addSubview(backView)
}
```

and my function

```
func pressBackButton(button: UIButton) {

    print("BUTTON PRESSED")
}
```

Comment: Try with `#selector(YourViewController.pressBackButton(button:))`

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine when i try your code with one change as i don't have backView. So replaced

```
backView.addSubview(backButton)
```

with

```
 self.view.addSubview(backButton)
```

I can see the log present in pressBackButton function on console on pressing the button. Make sure your console view is not disabled. shift+command+C shows the console view.